# Internal Stored Procedure Failure - ID_TransUserActionCreate

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

On a SQL Server 2014 12.0.4237.0 system, the following errors have been logged periodically (11 times in past 66 days):

> 2018-03-22 09:28:11.170 Error: 50101, Severity: 16, State: 10.
>   2018-03-22 09:28:11.170 Internal Stored Procedure Failure -  ID_TransUserActionCreate - SQL Error Number 0

As yet I haven't found any reference to an error with code 50101, and Google, amazingly, returns absolutely nothing for "ID_TransUserActionCreate".

As far as "what's happening at the time this is logged," I don't know yet as there are several databases on the system and we haven't yet started collecting detailed information to answer that question.  So this question is to ask if anyone knows, or has a good idea, what this message means and/or if it is something I should be concerned with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a user-defined error message that someone created on that instance.

[DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql)

> Is a user-defined error message number stored in the sys.messages
>   catalog view using sp_addmessage. Error numbers for user-defined error
>   messages should be greater than 50000. When msg_id is not specified,
>   RAISERROR raises an error message with an error number of 50000

You can find it in sys.messages

```
select * 
from sys.messages
where message_id = 50101
```

I would guess `ID_TransUserActionCreate` was a column name a table--lbut this is just a guess.

Comment: Thanks--that helped me track down which application is logging it, and now I know it can be ignored unless the users are reporting an issue.

Comment: Awesome @TonyHinkle--at least you are reading the error log and caring. Most don't do that!

Comment: Previous DBA set up something that filters out all the expected log messages and emails the other each day.  It's usually just annoying, but once in a while it turns out to be quite helpful.

Comment: I actually wrote something similar which allows you to explicitly search the error logs, or return everything minus a list of exclusions. I plan to dump this and some others on Git soon--i'll post back when i do